# Duplicate item custom listview with BaseAdapter

Tags: android, mysql, listview, android-listview, baseadapter

I try to show data from database mysql to listview with Custom ListView extends BaseAdapter. Data in database like :

tbl_userbook :

```
    id   | username  |  title          | category
   ------+-----------+-----------------+-------------
    1    | A         |  Java           | 1
    2    | B         |  VB.NET         | 1
    3    | C         |  Swing Java     | 1
    4    | D         |  Java Hibernate | 1
    5    | E         |  C#             | 1
    6    | F         |  Ruby           | 1
    7    | G         |  MySQL          | 1
    8    | H         |  Sqlite         | 1
    9    | I         |  PHP            | 1
    10   | J         |  MsSQL          | 1
```

My Question is Why listview showing duplicate item starting from id 1 to 6 and data id 7, 8, 9, 10 not shown at listview.

Data Shown at Listview like :

```
    | username  |  title          | 
    +-----------+-----------------+
    | A         |  Java           |
    | B         |  VB.NET         |
    | C         |  Swing Java     |
    | D         |  Java Hibernate |
    | E         |  C#             |
    | F         |  Ruby           |
    | A         |  Java           | < ----  duplicate starting from here
    | B         |  VB.NET         |
    | C         |  Swing Java     |
    | D         |  Java Hibernate |
```

BaseAdapter :

```
public class HomeListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList;
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

public HomeListViewAdapter(Context context,
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
    this.context = context;
    userList = arraylist;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return userList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    TextView tvUsername, tvTitle;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflator = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_home, parent, false);

        map = membersList.get(position);

        tvUsername = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvUsername);
        tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);

        tvUsername.setText(map.get(FragmentHome.USERNAME));
        tvTitle.setText(map.get(FragmentHome.TITLE));

    }
    return convertView;
```

Fragment

```
public class FragmentHome extends SherlockFragment {

public static String USERNAME = "username";
public static String TITLE = "title";

private ProgressDialog pDialog; 
JSONPostGet jPostget = new JSONPostGet();
JSONArray users = null;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList;

private static String url_getbook = "http://....../get_userbook.php";

ListView list;
HomeListViewAdapter homeadapter;

private static final String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String KEY_USERS = "users";
private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    userList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    new LoadUserBook().execute();
    return rootView;
}

class LoadUserBook extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait....");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category", "1"));
        JSONObject json = jPostget.makeHttpRequest(url_getbook, "GET", params);
        Log.d("All News Feed: ", json.toString());
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(KEY_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                users = json.getJSONArray(KEY_USERS);
                for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = users.getJSONObject(i);

                    String suname = c.getString(KEY_USERNAME);
                    String stitle = c.getString(KEY_TITLE);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(KEY_USERNAME, suname);
                    map.put(KEY_TITLE, stitle);

                    userList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // ...
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
                    list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview1);
                    homeadapter = new HomeListViewAdapter(getActivity(), userList);
                    list.setAdapter(homeadapter);
                    homeadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

}

Please help. Thanks for advance

Comment: Use userList.clear() inside doInBackground() method  like .  @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) { userList.clear()

Comment: lol. I juts remove it " if (convertView == null) " the problem solve, but can you kindly give me a reason why that's happening.

Comment: you shouldn't remove that.. it helps keep things smooth

Comment: where I have to put the code " userList.clear() " if use inside doInBackground(), data not shown?

Comment: @eric : so what should I do?

Comment: Best way to used `ArrayAdapter` with  `Model` class

Comment: @Dya Your arrayList is adding values repedetly, So I told you use userList.clear() inside starting of doInBackground() method.

Comment: Just look at my answer, you'll get the idea...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `getView` implementation is not correct. Try this -

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        TextView tvUsername, tvTitle;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflator = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_home, parent, false);   
        }


            map = membersList.get(position);

            tvUsername = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvUsername);
            tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);

            tvUsername.setText(map.get(FragmentHome.USERNAME));
            tvTitle.setText(map.get(FragmentHome.TITLE));

        return convertView;
}
```

Comment: @ Kshitij : Thank you, I use your suggestion .. my problem solved

Answer (score 2):

I think you did not add `else` to the condition specified for convertView as null.

So right now your code just setting data only for those views which are currently displaying, for the remaining data it repeats the view that have been previously initialized.

Just try like this, i m sure u'll get the solution:

```
if(convertView == null){
// some code here 
} 
else{
     holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your explanation, and Now I'm understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think getItem() should return userlist.get(position) and in onCreateView
map = membersList.get(position);
should be
ap = userlist.get(position);

Another thing is the else clause missing when convert view is not null.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    TextView tvUsername, tvTitle;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflator = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_home, parent, false);




    }else{
       LayoutInflater layoutInflator = convertView;

    }

     map = membersList.get(position);

        tvUsername = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvUsername);
        tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);

        tvUsername.setText(map.get(FragmentHome.USERNAME));
        tvTitle.setText(map.get(FragmentHome.TITLE));

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution : -

You have not implemented your Base adapter correctly.
android for performance reason recycle the views so you need to initialize your text image,etc. everytime.So you just need to put the initiliazation code outside the convertview null check.
Just do this:--

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

TextView tvUsername, tvTitle;

if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflator = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    convertView = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_home, parent, false);



    tvUsername = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvUsername);
    tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);



}
map = membersList.get(position);
tvUsername.setText(map.get(FragmentHome.USERNAME));
    tvTitle.setText(map.get(FragmentHome.TITLE));
return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
            // get the layout inflater

            LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            // create a ViewHolder reference
            ViewHolder holder = null;

            // check to see if the reused view is null or not, if is not
            // null then reuse it

            if (view == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                // check to see if the reused view is null or not, if is not
                // null then reuse it
                if (view == null) {
                    holder = new ViewHolder();

                    view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(
                            R.layout.listview_values, null);
                    holder.txt_date = (TextView) view
                            .findViewById(R.id.t_date);
                    holder.txt_intime = (TextView) view
                            .findViewById(R.id.txt_intime);
                    holder.txt_outtime = (TextView) view
                            .findViewById(R.id.txt_outtime);

                    // the setTag is used to store the data within this view
                    view.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    // the getTag returns the viewHolder object set as a tag
                    // to the view
                    holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
                    view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(
                            R.layout.listview_values, parent, false);
                }

            }
            // get the string item from the position "position" from array
            // list to put it on the TextView
            String date = attendence_webdata.get(position).get("A_date")
                    .toString();
            String intime = attendence_webdata.get(position)
                    .get("Ain_time").toString();
            String outtime = attendence_webdata.get(position)
                    .get("out_time").toString();
            if (date != null) {
                if (holder.txt_date != null) {
                    // set the item name on the TextView
                    holder.txt_date.setText(date);
                }
            }
            if (intime != null) {
                if (holder.txt_intime != null) {
                    // set the item name on the TextView
                    holder.txt_intime.setText(intime);
                }
            }
            if (outtime != null) {
                if (holder.txt_outtime != null) {
                    // set the item name on the TextView
                    holder.txt_outtime.setText(outtime);
                }
            }

            // this method must return the view corresponding to the data at
            // the specified position.
            return view;

        }
    }

}

/**
 * Static class used to avoid the calling of "findViewById" every time the
 * getView() method is called, because this can impact to your application
 * performance when your list is too big. The class is static so it cache
 * all the things inside once it's created.
 */
private static class ViewHolder {
    private TextView txt_outtime;
    private TextView txt_intime;
    private TextView txt_date;

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    attendence_webdata.clear();// where attendence_webdata is arraylistname
    list.setAdapter(null);     //where list is your listview name
}
```

check this code for when u back to parent activity and clear your data by .clear() method. i used this code in my app and its working so u can get idea from this code how can manage duplicate entries in list view

Answer (score 0):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View gridView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        gridView = new View(context);
    } else {
        gridView = (View) convertView;
    }
    gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.worker_listmain, null);
    // your source code here!!! Run 100%
    return gridView;
}
```

Comment: I got this problem  also, I find out the way to solve it!
Please use my source code :D SIMPLE is PERFECT :D

Answer (score 0):

i think you should have to add this line in your manifests file in your activity class.
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"